# Linking protobuf library using GNU makefile on Linux

Tags: linker, protocol-buffers, linker-errors, gnu-make

I know that the protobuf library must be linked using GNU makefile flags `-lprotobuf -lpthread` or maybe `-l:libprotobuf.so -lpthread`; however when I `make` with `-Wl,--verbose` I see the following output:

```
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/libprotobuf.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/libprotobuf.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/libprotobuf.a failed
attempt to open /lib/../lib64/libprotobuf.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/../lib64/libprotobuf.a failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib64/libprotobuf.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libprotobuf.a failed
attempt to open /lib64/libprotobuf.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libprotobuf.a failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/libprotobuf.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libprotobuf.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.a failed
attempt to open /lib/libprotobuf.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libprotobuf.a failed
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lprotobuf
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [playfun] Error 1
```

and using `-l:libprotobuf.so -lpthread` instead:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:libprotobuf.so
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [playfun] Error 1
```

and I know I have the Google protobuf library installed:

```
$ locate libprotobuf
/usr/lib/libprotobuf.so
/usr/lib/libprotobuf.so.6
/usr/lib/libprotobuf.so.6.0.0
/usr/lib64/libprotobuf.so
/usr/lib64/libprotobuf.so.6
/usr/lib64/libprotobuf.so.6.0.0
```

The code in question is the "tasbot" (learnfun/playfun) project found at http://tom7misc.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tom7misc/trunk/tasbot/ ; here is the makefile which I've tried to customize for my build (CentOS 5.8) and trim down to an SSCCE:

```
# Makefile made by tom7.
default: playfun learnfun
# tasbot
# emu_test

all: playfun tasbot emu_test objective_test learnfun weighted-objectives_test

CXXFLAGS=-Wall -Wno-deprecated -Wno-sign-compare -I/usr/local/include -fno-strict-aliasing

CXX=g++
CC=gcc
SDLARCH=x64

PROTOC=protoc
PROTO_HEADERS=marionet.pb.h
PROTO_OBJECTS=marionet.pb.o


# If you don't have SDL, you can leave these out, and maybe it still works.
#CCNETWORKING= -DMARIONET=1 -I SDL/include -I SDL_net
CCNETWORKING= -I /usr/include/SDL
#LINKSDL=  -mno-cygwin -lm -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -ldxguid
LINKSDL=  -lSDL
#LINKNETWORKING= $(LINKSDL) -lwsock32 -liphlpapi
#LINKNETWORKING= $(LINKSDL) -lprotobuf -lpthread
LINKNETWORKING= $(LINKSDL) -l:libprotobuf.so -lpthread
SDLOPATH=SDL/build
NETWORKINGOBJECTS= netutil.o $(PROTO_OBJECTS)

# PROFILE=-pg
PROFILE=

OPT=-O2

INCLUDES=-I "../cc-lib" -I "../cc-lib/city"
CPPFLAGS= $(CCNETWORKING) -DPSS_STYLE=1 -DDUMMY_UI -DHAVE_ASPRINTF -Wno-write-strings -m64 $(OPT) -DHAVE_ALLOCA -DNOWINSTUFF $(INCLUDES) $(PROFILE) $(FLTO)

CCLIBOBJECTS=../cc-lib/util.o ../cc-lib/arcfour.o ../cc-lib/base/stringprintf.o ../cc-lib/city/city.o ../cc-lib/textsvg.o

MAPPEROBJECTS=fceu/mappers/24and26.o fceu/mappers/51.o fceu/mappers/69.o fceu/mappers/77.o fceu/mappers/40.o fceu/mappers/6.o fceu/mappers/71.o fceu/mappers/79.o fceu/mappers/41.o fceu/mappers/61.o fceu/mappers/72.o fceu/mappers/80.o fceu/mappers/42.o fceu/mappers/62.o fceu/mappers/73.o fceu/mappers/85.o fceu/mappers/46.o fceu/mappers/65.o fceu/mappers/75.o fceu/mappers/emu2413.o fceu/mappers/50.o fceu/mappers/67.o fceu/mappers/76.o fceu/mappers/mmc2and4.o

# utils/unzip.o removed -- needs lz
UTILSOBJECTS=fceu/utils/ConvertUTF.o fceu/utils/general.o fceu/utils/memory.o fceu/utils/crc32.o fceu/utils/guid.o fceu/utils/endian.o fceu/utils/md5.o fceu/utils/xstring.o fceu/utils/unzip.o

# main binary
# PALETTESOBJECTS=palettes/conv.o

BOARDSOBJECTS=fceu/boards/01-222.o fceu/boards/32.o fceu/boards/gs-2013.o fceu/boards/103.o fceu/boards/33.o fceu/boards/h2288.o fceu/boards/106.o fceu/boards/34.o fceu/boards/karaoke.o fceu/boards/108.o fceu/boards/3d-block.o fceu/boards/kof97.o fceu/boards/112.o fceu/boards/411120-c.o fceu/boards/konami-qtai.o fceu/boards/116.o fceu/boards/43.o fceu/boards/ks7012.o fceu/boards/117.o fceu/boards/57.o fceu/boards/ks7013.o fceu/boards/120.o fceu/boards/603-5052.o fceu/boards/ks7017.o fceu/boards/121.o fceu/boards/68.o fceu/boards/ks7030.o fceu/boards/12in1.o fceu/boards/8157.o fceu/boards/ks7031.o fceu/boards/15.o fceu/boards/82.o fceu/boards/ks7032.o fceu/boards/151.o fceu/boards/8237.o fceu/boards/ks7037.o fceu/boards/156.o fceu/boards/830118C.o fceu/boards/ks7057.o fceu/boards/164.o fceu/boards/88.o fceu/boards/le05.o fceu/boards/168.o fceu/boards/90.o fceu/boards/lh32.o fceu/boards/17.o fceu/boards/91.o fceu/boards/lh53.o fceu/boards/170.o fceu/boards/95.o fceu/boards/malee.o fceu/boards/175.o fceu/boards/96.o fceu/boards/mmc1.o fceu/boards/176.o fceu/boards/99.o fceu/boards/mmc3.o fceu/boards/177.o fceu/boards/__dummy_mapper.o fceu/boards/mmc5.o fceu/boards/178.o fceu/boards/a9711.o fceu/boards/n-c22m.o fceu/boards/179.o fceu/boards/a9746.o fceu/boards/n106.o fceu/boards/18.o fceu/boards/ac-08.o fceu/boards/n625092.o fceu/boards/183.o fceu/boards/addrlatch.o fceu/boards/novel.o fceu/boards/185.o fceu/boards/ax5705.o fceu/boards/onebus.o fceu/boards/186.o fceu/boards/bandai.o fceu/boards/pec-586.o fceu/boards/187.o fceu/boards/bb.o fceu/boards/sa-9602b.o fceu/boards/189.o fceu/boards/bmc13in1jy110.o fceu/boards/sachen.o fceu/boards/193.o fceu/boards/bmc42in1r.o fceu/boards/sc-127.o fceu/boards/199.o fceu/boards/bmc64in1nr.o fceu/boards/sheroes.o fceu/boards/208.o fceu/boards/bmc70in1.o fceu/boards/sl1632.o fceu/boards/222.o fceu/boards/bonza.o fceu/boards/smb2j.o fceu/boards/225.o fceu/boards/bs-5.o fceu/boards/subor.o fceu/boards/228.o fceu/boards/cityfighter.o fceu/boards/super24.o fceu/boards/230.o fceu/boards/dance2000.o fceu/boards/supervision.o fceu/boards/232.o fceu/boards/datalatch.o fceu/boards/t-227-1.o fceu/boards/234.o fceu/boards/deirom.o fceu/boards/t-262.o fceu/boards/235.o fceu/boards/dream.o fceu/boards/tengen.o fceu/boards/244.o fceu/boards/edu2000.o fceu/boards/tf-1201.o fceu/boards/246.o fceu/boards/famicombox.o fceu/boards/transformer.o fceu/boards/252.o fceu/boards/fk23c.o fceu/boards/vrc2and4.o fceu/boards/253.o fceu/boards/ghostbusters63in1.o fceu/boards/vrc7.o fceu/boards/28.o fceu/boards/gs-2004.o fceu/boards/yoko.o

INPUTOBJECTS=fceu/input/arkanoid.o fceu/input/ftrainer.o fceu/input/oekakids.o fceu/input/suborkb.o fceu/input/bworld.o fceu/input/hypershot.o fceu/input/powerpad.o fceu/input/toprider.o fceu/input/cursor.o fceu/input/mahjong.o fceu/input/quiz.o fceu/input/zapper.o fceu/input/fkb.o fceu/input/mouse.o fceu/input/shadow.o

FCEUOBJECTS=fceu/asm.o fceu/cart.o fceu/cheat.o fceu/conddebug.o fceu/config.o fceu/debug.o fceu/drawing.o fceu/emufile.o fceu/fceu.o fceu/fds.o fceu/file.o fceu/filter.o fceu/ines.o fceu/input.o fceu/movie.o fceu/netplay.o fceu/nsf.o fceu/oldmovie.o fceu/palette.o fceu/ppu.o fceu/sound.o fceu/state.o fceu/unif.o fceu/video.o fceu/vsuni.o fceu/wave.o fceu/x6502.o

# fceu/drivers/common/config.o fceu/drivers/common/configSys.o
DRIVERS_COMMON_OBJECTS=fceu/drivers/common/args.o fceu/drivers/common/nes_ntsc.o fceu/drivers/common/cheat.o fceu/drivers/common/scale2x.o  fceu/drivers/common/scale3x.o fceu/drivers/common/scalebit.o fceu/drivers/common/hq2x.o fceu/drivers/common/vidblit.o fceu/drivers/common/hq3x.o
EMUOBJECTS=$(FCEUOBJECTS) $(MAPPEROBJECTS) $(UTILSOBJECTS) $(PALLETESOBJECTS) $(BOARDSOBJECTS) $(INPUTOBJECTS) $(DRIVERS_COMMON_OBJECTS)

#included in all tests, etc.
BASEOBJECTS=$(CCLIBOBJECTS) $(NETWORKINGOBJECTS) $(PROTOBUFOBJECTS)

TASBOT_OBJECTS=headless-driver.o config.o simplefm2.o emulator.o basis-util.o objective.o weighted-objectives.o motifs.o util.o

OBJECTS=$(BASEOBJECTS) $(EMUOBJECTS) $(TASBOT_OBJECTS)

%.pb.cc: %.proto
        $(PROTOC) $< --cpp_out=.

%.pb.h: %.proto
        $(PROTOC) $< --cpp_out=.

# without static, can't find lz or lstdcxx maybe?
#LFLAGS =  -m64 -Wl,--subsystem,console $(LINKNETWORKING) -lz $(OPT) $(FLTO) $(PROFILE) -static
LFLAGS =  -m64 -Wl,--verbose $(LINKNETWORKING) -lz $(OPT) $(FLTO) $(PROFILE) -static
# -Wl,--subsystem,console
# -static -fwhole-program
# -static

learnfun : $(OBJECTS) learnfun.o
        $(CXX) $^ -o $@ $(LFLAGS)

# XXX never implemented this.
showfun : $(OBJECTS) showfun.o
        $(CXX) $^ -o $@ $(LFLAGS)

tasbot : $(OBJECTS) tasbot.o
        $(CXX) $^ -o $@ $(LFLAGS)

playfun : $(OBJECTS) playfun.o
        $(CXX) $^ -o $@ $(LFLAGS)

emu_test : $(OBJECTS) emu_test.o
        $(CXX) $^ -o $@ $(LFLAGS)

objective_test : $(BASEOBJECTS) objective.o objective_test.o
        $(CXX) $^ -o $@ $(LFLAGS)
weighted-objectives_test : $(BASEOBJECTS) weighted-objectives.o weighted-objectives_test.o util.o
        $(CXX) $^ -o $@ $(LFLAGS)

test : emu_test objective_test weighted-objectives_test
        time ./emu_test
        time ./objective_test
        time ./weighted-objectives_test

clean :
        rm -f learnfun playfun showfun *_test *.o $(EMUOBJECTS) $(CCLIBOBJECTS) gmon.out

veryclean : clean cleantas

cleantas :
        rm -f prog*.fm2 deepest.fm2 heuristicest.fm2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I don't know why you have `-l:libprotobuf.so` here:

```
LINKNETWORKING= $(LINKSDL) -l:libprotobuf.so -lpthread
```

Shouldn't that just be `-lprotobuf` ?

Second, you have added the `-static` flag to your link line, which means your application will try to link statically.  That's why it's looking for `libprotobuf.a`, a static library.  But, as you show in your list of files, you don't have a static version of the protobuf library installed, only shared libraries.

Comment: Thanks. Reading the man pages I couldn't figure out why `-lprotobuf` was trying to link to libprotobuf.so.a instead of libprotobuf.so. Unlike the original developer I shouldn't need to do static linking. I removed `-static` which worked!